# valid json doesnt work

Tags: php, json, response

I am trying to decode a JSON string in PHP,but somehow the json_decode doesnt like my string, i think it is not valid json. The thing that is very strange to me is, that if i put the json response in a variable manually, it is working. If i write the json response out in the browser, and i write the content of the variable, both are completely the same, like this:

```
{"id":455463,"Created":"2016-04-30T14:20:38.09","SenderCompanyName":"x","InvoiceNumber":"2555","PaymentDueDate":"2016-04-30T00:00:00","ToBePaidAmount":350.0000}
```

If i look in the webpage source, the content is also completely the same. I have also tryed to convert to UTF8, but no change.

How do you guys usually debug this, or what did i forget ?

---

code:

```
// calling web service and saving json response in variable  
$json_response = CallAPI($method, $url, $json_request);  

// the response contain some unvalid character in the end, so i am removing it  
$json_response = substr($json_response, 0, strpos($json_response, "}"));  

// trying to decode it, IT PRINTS OUT NULL  
var_dump(json_decode($json_response, true));  



// copying the json response from the above and putting it into a variable  
$json_response = '{"id":455433,"Created":"2016-04-30T12:55:12.313","SenderCompanyName":"x","InvoiceNumber":"2525","PaymentDueDate":"2016-04-30T00:00:00","ToBePaidAmount":350.0000}';

// trying to decode it, IT PRINTS OUT THE RESULT SUCCESFULLY
var_dump(json_decode($json_response, true));
```

Comment: Json is valid by itself.

Comment: Quotes around value for ToBePaidAmount? "350.0000"

Comment: You have to run json_last_error()

Comment: omg cant get json_last_error to work, maybe my PHP version is too old

Comment: It's not as if minimum versions required by functions were not documented :-?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$json = '{"id":455463,"Created":"2016-04-30T14:20:38.09","SenderCompanyName":"x","InvoiceNumber":"2555","PaymentDueDate":"2016-04-30T00:00:00","ToBePaidAmount":350.0000}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
I had forget to add this in my CURL OPTIONS:

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

After adding this, its working fine

Comment: Not only is this code nowhere in your question—it also contradicts the information provided in it :-?

Comment: thats right, sometimes the solution is in another place than you expected

Comment: but the comments were not helpful, most of them didnt read my question well